# Django Model with out auto generated id field

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

[image: Model.py Image] --
[image: Migrate Query]

basically a "product(Rodamiento)" can have one, none or many "equivalents(Equivalente)"

when I create the "equivalent" class, Django auto generates an "id" field. 
¿is there a way to avoid that?, I need to transfer data from another DB, that "id" field makes it harder to do it

I'm using SQLite DB and SQLiteStudio

Comment: Set another field with `primary_key=True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a new model it by default id field with `primary key` you just add the another field as `primary key`so django not create a id fields with `primary key`

at list one fields have in model that have a primary key if you not specify any it take `id` so add another fields with `primary key` here i give a link to see
[auto add id fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

You can create a model without an auto-increment primary key false it may work easy to transfer, but you cannot create one without a primary key.

Comment: It worked but i found a problem, i can only make 1 equivalent. i can add more if i add it from SQLite Studio. Tried adding `unique=False` but it didn't work

Comment: i see, i need to have an id field. i will have to create another .cvs with that extra field then. Thank you